# command redirection issue

Tags: c#, command-line, io, standards

here is my code

```
//Create process
System.Diagnostics.Process pProcess = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

//strCommand is path and file name of command to run
pProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "ffmpeg.exe";

//strCommandParameters are parameters to pass to program
pProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "-i " + videoName;

pProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

//Set output of program to be written to process output stream
pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

//Start the process
pProcess.Start();

//Get program output
string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

//Wait for process to finish
pProcess.WaitForExit();
```

The command works, but `strOutput` string is empty, results are shown within the console. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible the program is writing its output to StandardError instead of StandardOutput.  Try using `.RedirectStandardError = true` and then `.pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd()` to capture that output.

If you need the possibility of capturing both standard error and standard out in (roughly) the proper interleave, you will likely need to use the async versions with callbacks on `OutputDataReceived` and `ErrorDataReceived` and using BeginOutput/ErrorReadLine.

Comment: Yes that actually solved.

Can I also do something like

string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
strOutput = pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

Comment: You can, but you will get the messages out-of-order (e.g. all of the standardError will be after standardOutput).  This might be fine for your purpose, but if you need it together in the right order, you'll have to use async as mentioned in my post.

Answer (score -2):

Try to capture Std Error too as on any event of error, it will be used instead.

```
        //Set output of program to be written to process output stream
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        pProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

        //Start the process
        pProcess.Start();

        //Wait for process to finish
        pProcess.WaitForExit();

        //Get program output
        string strError = pProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
        string strOutput = pProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

I just wonder why you wait for exit WaitForExit after reading the output, it should be in reversed order as your app may dump more until it finally completes the ops

Comment: "I just wonder why you wait for exit WaitForExit after reading the output, it should be in reversed order as your app may dump more until it finally completes the ops" - this is explicitly WRONG.  Doing so can lead to deadlocks.  Per MSDN: "The code example avoids a deadlock condition by calling p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd before p.WaitForExit. A deadlock condition can result if the parent process calls p.WaitForExit before p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd and the child process writes enough text to fill the redirected stream."

Comment: Link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.redirectstandardoutput.aspx